# Making an insert with comma's around the keys and values (loaded from array)

Tags: php

I am making a really small script, that allows you to make an insert query, based on an array.

So the only thing that you need to do is define the `$table` and add an array to the function.

```
public function makeRecord($table, $array){

    $array_keys = array_keys($array);
    $array_values = array_values($array);
    $keys = implode(',', $array_keys);
    $values = implode(',', $array_values);
    $this->DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($keys)
    VALUES ($values)";
    return $this->DB->exec($sql);

}
```

The next code will generate an SQL query like this.
`INSERT INTO Users (UserName,Password) VALUES (daan,welkom01)`.

But it needs to be

`INSERT INTO Users ('UserName', 'Password') VALUES ('daan','welkom01')`
What is the best way to fix this :)?

Comment: `implode()` doesn't care about array keys, so `array_values()` is unnecessary.  Prepared statements are in order here.  Have you researched this site before posting your question?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting single quotes around the column names. If quotes of any kind are required, they should be backticks (`\``)

Comment: Also you'd want to implement some sort of protection against SQL injection attacks - such as using parameterized queries instead of building queries like this by yourself.